# How to access the control identifiers in pywinauto? - Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywinauto

I'm fairly new to programming but i am actively practicing to get better. Can someone tell me how do i access control identifiers since this application begins with a number and has spaces in the name. This is what i have so far. I am getting an obvious syntax error but i don't know how to correct it.

```
appWin = Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\8x8-Work\8x8 Work.exe")
appWin = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='8x8 Work (Available)',timeout=100)

appWin.8x8-Work.print_control_identifiers()
```

```
appWin.8x8-Work.print_control_identifiers()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Maybe that Unicode characters and special symbols usage is possible through an item access in a dictionary like manner as `appWin['8x8-Work'].print_control_identifiers()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try appWin.Work.print_control_identifiers()